# Backup of FileGroups Including Primary

Tags: sql-server, backup, filegroups

I want to back up my DB. I have some huge tables in some specific `FileGroups` which I want to exclude them to be getting `backup`.
I have tried this script:

```
BACKUP DATABASE TestDB
   FILEGROUP = 'PRIMARY',  
   FILEGROUP = 'Temp_FG',
   FILEGROUP = 'Index_FG'
TO DISK = 'E:\TestBackup\Test.bak';  
GO
```

But I am getting this error:

```
The primary filegroup cannot be backed up as a file backup because the database is using the SIMPLE recovery model. Consider taking a partial backup by specifying READ_WRITE_FILEGROUPS.
```

What can I do to get the backup including only these 3 FileGroups or excluding the 'Dump_FG'?

- 'Dump_FG' FileGroup is not `ReadOnly`.

Answer (score 1):

That is just the way that SQL Server work. If you were able to exclude read-write filegroups in simple recovery, then you wouldn't be able to restore them. A restore need log backups to apply modifications to the data you just restored. Since you can't do log backup in simple mode, then those filegroups in your backup would be "doomed" - for even inaccessible (I believe that the state is "defunct" in SQL Server). And you cannot have a doomed primary filegroup. If you have data which is irrelevant for you,then consider truncating those table to get rid of the data or set them to read-only and exclude them.

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Think about (and test) your recovery plan.

If you could exclude a read-write filegroup from a partial backup in the `SIMPLE` model, you could never recover that filegroup beyond the last full or differential backup, nor restore from a later partial backup of other read-write filegroups. Otherwise, the database would be inconsistent.

Comment: I do not need those tables and they will be filled in future through gathering data from another servers.